# Are the Future Sound and Colorful Tone trophies obtainable in the Japanese version after the DLCs were delisted?

Tags: project-diva-future-tone

A couple of months ago, the Colorful Tone and Future Sound DLC Packs for the Japanese edition of Project Diva Future Tone were delisted from the PlayStation Store, as you can see in the following picture:

[image]

For a comparison, this is the US PlayStation store where you can see Future Sound (3rd on bottom row) and Colorful Tone (6th on bottom row):

[image]

Because of this, the following trophies are no longer obtainable:

- リズムゲームマスター[FS] (Rhythm Game Master [FS])
- ランクアップ！[FS] (Rank Up! [FS])
- リズムゲームクリア！[FS] (Rhythm Game Cleared! [FS])
- モジュールスタイリスト[FS] (Module Stylist [FS])
- 撮影勢！？[FS] (Paparazzi!? [FS])
- PVウォッチャー[FS] (Music Video Aficionado [FS])
- リズムゲームマスター[CT] (Rhythm Game Master [CT])
- ランクアップ！[CT] (Rank Up! [CT])
- リズムゲームクリア！[CT] (Rhythm Game Cleared! [CT])
- モジュールスタイリスト[CT] (Module Stylist [CT])
- 撮影勢！？[CT] (Paparazzi!? [FS])
- PVウォッチャー[CT] (Music Video Aficionado [CT])

Are this trophies obtainable somehow in the Japanese edition of the game?

Please note that Future Tone DX has a [completely different set of trophies](https://psnprofiles.com/trophies/6893-%E5%88%9D%E9%9F%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%82%AF-project-diva-future-tone-dx/) with a Platinum, unlike normal Future Tone.